# How to select unique domain values that are not shared with other attribute values?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to find the courses (knamn) that only Lennart have taught in but not Alan or Kjell.

The result should look like this:

```
knamn   
Innovation och entreprenorskap  
Manniska datorinteraktion
```

How do I retrieve the view above from the following table below (this table is called z);

```
kkod        namn        knamn
----------  ----------  ----------------------------------
TIG058      Alan        Programmeringsteknik och databaser
TIG058      Alan        Programmeringsteknik och databaser
TIG058      Alan        Programmeringsteknik och databaser
TIG059      Alan        Systemutvecklingsprojekt
TIG059      Alan        Systemutvecklingsprojekt
TIG059      Alan        Systemutvecklingsprojekt
TIG163      Alan        Beslutsstodsystem
TIG163      Alan        Beslutsstodsystem
TIG163      Alan        Beslutsstodsystem
TIG164      Alan        Interaktionsdesign
TIG164      Alan        Interaktionsdesign
TIG164      Alan        Interaktionsdesign
TIG164      Alan        Interaktionsdesign
TIG164      Alan        Interaktionsdesign
TIG165      Alan        Informatik som vetenskap
TIG165      Alan        Informatik som vetenskap
TIG015      Kjell       Informationsteknologi och informat
TIG015      Kjell       Informationsteknologi och informat
TIG063      Kjell       Informationsteknologi och samhalle
TIG063      Kjell       Informationsteknologi och samhalle
TIG063      Kjell       Informationsteknologi och samhalle
TIG063      Kjell       Informationsteknologi och samhalle
TIG162      Kjell       Affarssystem
TIG162      Kjell       Affarssystem
TIG162      Kjell       Affarssystem
TIG167      Kjell       Fordjupning i programmering
TIG167      Kjell       Fordjupning i programmering
TIA015      Lennart     Innovation och entreprenorskap
TIG015      Lennart     Informationsteknologi och informat
TIG058      Lennart     Programmeringsteknik och databaser
TIG058      Lennart     Programmeringsteknik och databaser
TIG059      Lennart     Systemutvecklingsprojekt
TIG059      Lennart     Systemutvecklingsprojekt
TIG059      Lennart     Systemutvecklingsprojekt
TIG061      Lennart     Manniska datorinteraktion
TIG061      Lennart     Manniska datorinteraktion
TIG162      Lennart     Affarssystem
TIG163      Lennart     Beslutsstodsystem
TIG163      Lennart     Beslutsstodsystem
TIG163      Lennart     Beslutsstodsystem
TIG163      Lennart     Beslutsstodsystem
TIG163      Lennart     Beslutsstodsystem
TIG165      Lennart     Informatik som vetenskap
TIG165      Lennart     Informatik som vetenskap
TIG165      Lennart     Informatik som vetenskap
TIG165      Lennart     Informatik som vetenskap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only Lennart have taught...

With conditional aggregation:

```
select knamn
from tablename
group by knamn
having count(*) = sum(namn = 'Lennart');
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fS845XqdJvSvsP8PhJTHJp/0).
Results:

```
| knamn                          |
| ------------------------------ |
| Innovation och entreprenorskap |
| Manniska datorinteraktion      |
```

Comment: Niiiceee this worked as well. So I guess all these selection conditions all have to do with aggregation. Aggregation is key i guess lol ty

Comment: And in this case:`sum(namn = 'Lennart')` conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want aggregation:

```
select knamn
from t
where name in ('Lennart', 'Alan', 'Kjell')
group by knamn
having min(name) = max(name) and   -- Ensures that only one of the three names match
       min(name) = 'Lennart';      -- And that name is Lennart
```

Comment: Thank you, got the result I wanted. I have no idea how the "having" statement there at the bottom makes sense like with min(name) = max (name)?? Anyways it worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
select knamn
from tablename
group by knamn
having avg(namn='Lennart')=1; -- 1 is only possible if all the namn per knamn are 'Lennart'
```